# How to align div which having different height?

Tags: javascript, html

I need a Javascript code to append new DIV's in this following model. I will use default ordering like float left, those items are ordering in the horizontal manner. Please help me

```
<div id="maincontainer">

<div style="height:100px;width:150px; float:left; border:1px solid red; margin:5px;">smallest</div>
<div style="height:200px;width:150px; float:left; border:1px solid red; margin:5px;">largest</div>
<div style="height:150px;width:150px; float:left; border:1px solid red; margin:5px;">middle</div>
<div style="height:100px;width:150px; float:left; border:1px solid red; margin:5px;">middle2</div>
<div style="height:190px;width:150px; float:left; border:1px solid red; margin:5px;">middle3</div>
<div style="height:160px;width:150px; float:left; border:1px solid red; margin:5px;">middle4</div>

</div>
```

```js
<javascript>
$('div').sort(function (a, b) {
    return $(a).height() > $(b).height() ? 1 : -1;  
}).appendTo('body');
</javascript>
```

Output I'm getting is

[image]

I need like this

[image]

Comment: If jQuery is an option, then try http://masonry.desandro.com/

Answer (score 1):

You can to create 3 or that you need columns with fixed width and put blocks in this w/o floating.

For example:

```
<div id="first_col">
  <div class="block">
    content
  </div>
  <div class="block">
    content2
  </div>
</div>

<div id="second_col">
  <div class="block">
    content
  </div>
  <div class="block">
    content2
  </div>
</div>

<div id="last_col">
  <div class="block">
    content
  </div>
  <div class="block">
    content2
  </div>
</div>
```

And apped by JS new blocks into div with class, where height is minimal.